# Upgraded Drush 8 to 9 Site Alias Not Working

Tags: drupal, drush, acquia, lando

I moved from using Docksal to Acquia ADS (Lando) which automatically upgraded my Drush from 8 to 9. My local site works fine but I can't get Drush 9 to "see" my Drupal 8 site. The aliases seem to have been created and added to the drush/sites folder and running drush site:alias does show them. However running drush status shows my Drupal root as /app. My Drupal root is /app/docroot. My alias files do have this as their root (for local). I'm not sure why Drush doesn't use the alias files it knows about. I've tried:

drush @self(or @local) list and I get some commands and this statement at the end:

> [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.

Doing drush @local(or @self) cr returns:

> In BootstrapHook.php line 32:   Bootstrap failed. Run your command
> with -vvv for more information.

With -vvv:

> Exception trace:   at
> /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:32
> Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at
> /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook()
> at
> /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize()
> at
> /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:145
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at
> /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:289
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at
> /app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:221
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
> /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1005
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
> /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
> /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
> /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at
> /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
> require() at /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

drush status:

```
PHP binary    : /usr/local/bin/php
PHP config    :
PHP OS        : Linux
Drush script  : /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush
Drush version : 10.2.2 <-- Had 9.0.0 but currently trying 10, same issue
Drush temp    : /tmp
Drush configs : /root/.drush/drush.yml
                /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
                /app/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root   : /app
```

self.site.yml:

```
local:
  root: /app/docroot
  uri: example.lndo.site
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out. No matter how many ways you try to tell Drush where to look to find your Drupal root, none of it will matter until you edit your composer.json file. Turns out the key to making Drush 9+ work is changing the name in composer.
My composer.json file name went from:
"name": "drupal/drupal",
to:
"name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",

I don't think this feature was documented anywhere so I'm posting it here in response to my own question in case this helps anyone else.

Comment: Thanks ! that was this easy.

Comment: Wow thank you! Would've never figured that out. I don't understand, but I don't care.

Comment: Since it's been over a year since this was answered, does anyone know if this has been documented anywhere yet?

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is an older question, however with Drupal 8 recently reaching end of life, and the high probability of many people (like myself) scrambling to upgrade now that clients have realized the risks of using EOL software, I want to take a moment to explain why @r00t's answer works.

r00t is correct that changing the `"name"` value in `composer.json` fixed the issue, however, the value that is set is not limited to `drupal-composer/drupal-project`.  This seems to stem from the package `webflo/drupal-finder` and the way it works.

`webflow/drupal-finder` is a requirement of `drush/drush`, so it's going to be included even if you haven't added it manually. It's also a requirement of a couple of others that you may or may not have installed, like `palantirnet/drupal-rector` (which as a side note, is really helpful for this upgrade).

Within the code for `drupal-finder` is a method that looks for the install path of Drupal core based on a few items within your `composer.json` file.

Here is the code from DrupalFinder::isValidRoot()

```php
foreach ($json['extra']['installer-paths'] as $install_path => $items) {
    if (in_array('type:drupal-core', $items) ||
        in_array('drupal/core', $items) ||
        in_array('drupal/drupal', $items)) {
        $this->composerRoot = $path;
  // @todo: Remove this magic and detect the major version instead.
  if (($install_path == 'core') || ((isset($json['name'])) && ($json['name'] == 'drupal/drupal'))) {
    $install_path = '';
  } elseif (substr($install_path, -5) == '/core') {
    $install_path = substr($install_path, 0, -5);
  }
....
```

Which is telling `drupal-finder` that if the `"name"` value is `drupal/drupal` then the install path of the site is at the base of the project, however if it is not `drupal/drupal` then use a value from `extra.installer-paths` to find the site install.

I'm still not aware if this is documented anywhere on either `webflo/drupal-finder` or in `drush/drush`, but understanding why it was an issue helped me out tremendously.

### TL;DR:

If your site's docroot lives next to your `vendor` folder, change the name in `composer.json` to anything that isn't `drupal/drupal`.  If your `vendor` folder lives inside your docroot, `drupal/drupal` will work for you.